# Multiple modals with same JS file and same classes

Tags: javascript, php

Can i have multiple modals with the same JS file and same classes and ids? I built this code:

```
<button id='myBtn'>Comanda/Reducere</button>
        <div id='myModal' class='modal'>
         <div class='modal-content'>
           <span class='close'>&times;</span>
           <form class='' action='includes\comanda.inc.php?id=".$row_oferte['id']. " ' method='post'>
             <input type='text' name='nr_comanda' placeholder='Numar comanda'>
             <input type='text' name='termen_livrare' placeholder='Termend de livrare'>
             <input type='submit' value='Coamnda'>
           </form>
           </br>
           <form class='' action='includes/reducere.inc.php?id=".$row_oferte['id']. " ' method='post'>
             <input type='text' name='reducere_update' placeholder='Reducere'>
             <input type='submit' value='Modifica'>
           </form>
         </div>
         <script type='text/javascript' src='js/button.js'></script>
```

in the ofertare.php file and i want to use this modal in comanda.php file but with other content and it is not opening the modal in the comanda.php file.

The JS file is button.js:

```
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');

// Get the button that opens the modal
var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks on the button, open the modal
btn.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "block";
}

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "none";
}

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target == modal) {
        modal.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

Comment: No you can not have multiple elements with same ID, id is a unique identifier and must be unique in whole document. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id

Comment: Okay, thanks, but how can i do what i want to do?

Comment: Could you explain a bit more what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: So, i am trying to build a website. And in ofertare.php file i am having a table and for each row i have a modal button  which is opening and asking for some data and moving that row in another table that i wanna display in comanda.php file. The problem is that i wanna do the same in comanda.php file. And i can't use the same modal and i don't know how to do this...

Comment: Can't you add the modal codes in the footer? that way you would be able to re-use it on all pages.

Comment: But the content of the modals are gonna be different...

Comment: Have you tried adding different modal for different pages?

Comment: Yea, but i dont know js very well and i tried to change the ids and classes in html and in the js file but i think i missed something...

Comment: If you use same id, then it won't work, but there shouldn't be any problem with same classes. Are you using any third party plugin/library for modal?

Comment: I'm using bootstrap. I tried to copy the Js code and change de ids but in didnt work and i changed them also in html...

Comment: I have same problem, no answer - having 2 modals, different ids, trying to close them using the same unique close span.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of using multiple modal in a single page.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /> 
</head>
<body>
<button data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal1" class="btn btn-default">Modal 1</button>
<button data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal2" class="btn btn-default">Modal 2</button>
<button data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal3" class="btn btn-default">Modal 3</button>
 
<!-- Modal 1 -->
<div class="modal fade" id="modal1" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="modal1Label">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="modal1Label">Modal 1</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
       I am modal 1
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- end Modal 1 -->

<!-- Modal 2 -->
<div class="modal fade" id="modal2" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="modal2Label">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="modal2Label">Modal 2</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        I am modal 2
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- end Modal 2 --> 

<!-- Modal 3 -->
<div class="modal fade" id="modal3" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="modal3Label">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="modal3Label">Modal 3</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        I am modal 3
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- end Modal 3 -->  
 
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Jsbin of the above snippet https://jsbin.com/fenehel/edit?html,output
For your situation, you could add modals to the footer according to your needs, and then use them on respective pages. 
You can learn more about bootstrap modals here http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals

Comment: I tried to use this code also in the footer but it is not working correct. It is opening the modal but everything is transparent...but it is opening it because i saw it in the inspect element and also because i can't use the scroll till i don't click somewhere....

Comment: If everything appears transparent, then there might be css issues, as for can't scroll issue, it's default behavior of bootstrap modal, when modal is opened you can't scroll body. I would recommend reading more about bootstrap modals http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals

Comment: Yea,i know why i can't scroll, but i can't find the css issue...i'm still searching it...i think there might because i use bootstrap css from the theme and also the default bootstrap css file